# How to transpose rows into columns in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, transpose

[image: my data]

I want to transform/transpose this DF into an other DF with one row containing all the columns:
for exemple i will have columns GearLeverPosition_v2_count, GearLeverPosition_v2_mean ... with the index 0 having the values for each one.

Comment: could you add in the question an example of the desired result. looks like you want a vector containing metrics (count, mean) for each column. Is that right?

Comment: yeah it's right i want only one raw and a lot of columns

Comment: then you don't want to transpose it. you are getting several answers that tell you how to transpose, since it's what you asked in the title.

Answer (score 3):

Same as in numpy, to transpose a DataFrame in pandas you can:

```py
df.T
```

or equivalently:

```py
df.transpose()
```

Comment: df.transpose() doesnt make it, i've already tried, i want to transform the whole data frame with one line and severals columns. my final df should have 8 columns having GearLeverPosition_v2 + prefix, same for other columns.

Comment: for now i have 226 columns, i want one line with 226 x 8 columns

Comment: Right, then you mean a [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

Comment: i tried with valueError : no groupe keys passed –

Answer (score 1):

You can use transpose() function to transpose index and columns. Reflect the DataFrame over its main diagonal by writing rows as columns and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

There's a transpose function in pandas

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html?highlight=transpose#pandas.DataFrame.transpose

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])

# insert col in array
newCol = [0,0,0,0,0]
arrNew = (np.vstack([arr.transpose(), newCol])).transpose()

array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 6, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 0]])
```