# Create new a DataFrame from itself with its transpose

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new DataFrame with its transpose:

It's look like a matrix multiplication of its transpose, M x M^T

```
        Groups      
Area    g1  g2  g3  g4
a1     1    0   0   0
a2     0    0   0   1
a3     0    0   0   0
a4     0    0   1   0
a5     1    0   0   0
a6     0    0   1   0
```

its transpose

```
        Area                
    a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
g1  1   0   0   0   1   0
g2  0   0   0   0   0   0
g3  0   0   0   1   0   1
g4  0   1   0   0   0   0
```

output should be:

example row a1, has column g1; from its transpose, row g1 has a1  and a5

```
Area    a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
a1      1               1   
a2          1               
a3                      
a4                 1        1
a5      1               1   
a6                 1        1
```

Comment: If you just want transpose, you can use df.transpose() with pandas.
If not, what does the example dataframe mean?

Comment: Shouldn't the last `a6` be the same as `a4`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transpose rows into columns in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72458830/how-to-transpose-rows-into-columns-in-python)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado It's not a transpose.

Comment: Oh I see. This is more like matrix multiplication. Thanks @TheMaster

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

```
import numpy as np

arr1 =np.array([[1,    0,   0,   0],
    [0,    0,   0,   1],
    [0,    0,   0 ,  0],
    [0,    0 ,  1,   0],
    [1,    0,   0,   0],
    [0,    0,   1,   0]
    ])

arr2 =arr1.T
np.dot(arr1, arr2)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```